# Session Replication issue between Cloud Foundry app instances after Scaling app's instance

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-session, spring-data-redis, session-replication

I have Spring Boot application which binds with ClearDb(MySQL) and Redis Cloud as a backing store. My application will create an simple account and stores in MySQL. I have used `spring-session-data-redis` to store `HttpSession` session attributes into Redis cloud. I can able to store all session attributes into Redis Cloud.

In `manifest.yml` file, I mentioned `instances` to 2. Once App gets started with 2 instances, session replication works between app's instances. When I do scale out process to app's instance to 3. Newly created instance started receiving traffic but when It tried to get session information it throws `NullPointerException` and shows response code `500` with error message as `Internal Server Error`. It seems session replication is not working on 3rd app's instance and session replication not working on scaling app's instances though.

How can I resolve this issue? Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has solved. It is because `HttpSession` is not autowired to use in other methods in controller class.